# CSS 2 Column Form Layout Using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a form layout as pictured below using Flexbox. The included example is a mock up from a portfolio site I'm building.

This is my form code, I've tried lots of different ways of getting it to look like my mock up using Flexbox, but haven't succeeded. Thanks for the help on this!

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name*">
    <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address*">
    <textarea placeholder="Subject"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND!">
</form>
```

[image: Mocked up Form]

Comment: show your CSS code also...

Comment: You could try to use the form attribute ... have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644128/html-input-field-outside-of-form

Comment: I really didn't get far with my CSS, so I didn't think I had enough to even post it. I've tried having the first 3 input elements in a flex container, set wth flex-flow: column. That works okay for the first three, but then getting the right message box to that side has been challenging.

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/t5ee15y2/359/

Comment: This is just what I want it to look like, thanks for the help! I'll see if I can see how you made this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the existing markup you can use `flexbox` column layout.

The main setting making the children to occupy the space how you want is:

- `flex-container` need a height, here 60vh, so flex items know where and how to break flow
- Message `textarea` having 100% height, which makes it break the flow and take full height
- Subject `textarea` having `flex: 1`, which makes it take the available space left

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60vh;
  border: 1px solid black;  
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container * {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container :nth-child(2),
.flex-container :nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.flex-container :nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-container :nth-child(4) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name*">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address*">
  <textarea placeholder="Subject"></textarea>
  <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." rows="7"></textarea>
</form>
```

---

If you can change markup and/or don't want to set a height on the `flex-container`, you can add a `row` layout to the above sample

Its main setting is:

- `flex-container`, remove the `flex-direction: column` so its direction is `row`
- Add a wrapper around the input's and subject `textarea`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;  
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-container > * {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.flex-wrapper :nth-child(2),
.flex-wrapper :nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.flex-wrapper :nth-child(3),
.flex-container > textarea {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name*">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address*">
    <textarea placeholder="Subject"></textarea>
  </div>
  <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." rows="7"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the time that you put into this.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can modify the html you can add wrappers (flex left/right) and the css becomes easier (i think)

```
<form class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex left">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name*"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address*"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Subject"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="flex right">
    <textarea placeholder="Type your message here..." rows="7"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

and then you need this css which also accommodates for very small screens less than 400 px (responsive design)... adjust the media query to your liking

```
.flex {
  padding: 10px;  
}
.flex input,
.flex textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex input,
  .flex textarea {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
   }

  .flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;

    padding: 10px;  
  }
  .left {
    width: 40%;
   }
  .right {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    width: 60%;               /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
    -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  }
}
```

here it is in action https://jsfiddle.net/GiorgosK/L3w7t0k7/