# Posting values of input fields outside form tag containing submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 3 input fields which are not inside a form tag. I cannot add them inside the form because the three input fields are at different locations on the same page.

I want to post input values outside form tag as well when i press submit button. How can i do that?

```
<input input type="text" id="elecr"  value="2" name="electricity"></input>
<input input type="text" id="3wheel"  value="3" name="threewheel"></input>
<input input type="text" id="4wheel"  value="2" name="fourwheel"></input>

<form action="/savedata" method="post">
2Wheeler: <input type="text" id="2wheeler"  value="0" name="twowheeler"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to prevent default submit event and manually submit the form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input field OUTSIDE of a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644128/html-input-field-outside-of-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write javascript to handle submit event
2. On submit event append your input with form data
3. Submit

For reference please refer
[Adding POST parameters before submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993834/adding-post-parameters-before-submit/993897)

```
$( 'form' ).submit(function ( e ) {
    var data;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append( 'electricity', $('#elecr').val());
    data.append( 'threewheel', $('#3wheel').val());
    data.append( 'fourwheel', $('#4wheel').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'savedata.php',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert( data );
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the values of all the input fields through jquery and submit your form through ajax on the click of your submit button.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'electricity'  : $('input[name=electricity]').val(),
        'threewheel'   : $('input[name=threewheel]').val(),
        'fourwheel'    : $('input[name=fourwheel]').val(),
        'twowheeler'   : $('input[name=twowheeler]').val(),
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'savedata.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true
    })
```

you are able to log and also able to error handling in your jquery.