# Add external form elements to FormData

Tags: javascript, html, forms, fetch-api, form-data

In HTML5 we can use the `form` attribute on form control elements to have them be part of a form other then the one they're childs of, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644180/3735561).

These elements however seem not to be considered when passing the form element to the `FormData` constructor, as described [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#prepopulating_from_a_html_form_element).

Is there a way to have these 'external' controls be included in a way that I then can send the *complete* form data via a fetch Request?

I am aware, that I could loop through the external elements and `append` them to the FormData instance like so

```
let formData = new FormData(form);

for (const external of document.body.querySelectorAll('[form="' + form.name + '"]')) {
    formData.append(external.name, external.value);
}
```

However I hoped for a more convenient way, especially taking in consideration the extra cases and checks I would have to make it work with radiobuttons etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements on which you use the `form` attribute are included in the `FormData` constructor when you pass down the form element. For example:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("myform");
const formData = new FormData(form); 
    
for (const [key, value] of formData) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}\n`);
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" id="myform">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<input form="myform" type="email" name="email" value="email@email.com" />
```

As you can see, the **email input** element, which is outside of the form element, gets included in the form's `FormData`. 
My guess is that you may have misued the form attribute, if this doesn't help I would suggest you to share some of the code you have wrote in order to make the problem more clear.

Comment: how embarrassing. You are of course right, I _was_ simply misusing the form attribute and you can actually already see my mistake in the code snippet in the original question: I was referencing the form via it's `name` attribute, not it's `id` (I usually try to avoid IDs).
Guess you've earned your 50rep. (as soon as SO let's me do so).